# Open Chrome with specific VPN Tunnel

Tags: openvpn

I have multiple VPN tunnels open by calling this in several terminals:

`sudo openvpn --config <config_file>`

now I have a routing table from calling `netstat -nr | grep tun` which shows multiple web interfaces: "tun1,tun2,etc." The most recently opened VPN tunnel is the "default" one, where all my traffic is routed through. However I want to launch google chrome with any one of the VPN's, not just the default one. Is there an argument I can pass when launching chrome from the terminal? Something like this:

`google-chrome --interface tun1`